# How to store key/value pair in C#(4.0)?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I would like to know how to Store Key/Value Pair in C# 4.0?

For example, in Java `HashTable` or `HashMap` used to store key/value pairs.. But How i do it in C#?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) class, or a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) if you know the specific types that you're storing.

Example:

```
// Loose-Type
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
hashTable.Add("key", "value");
hashTable.Add("int value", 2);
// ...
foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in hashTable) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", dictionaryEntry.Key, dictionaryEntry.Value);
}

// Strong-Type
Dictionary<string, int> intMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
intMap.Add("One", 1);
intMap.Add("Two", 2);
// ..
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyValue in intMap) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
}
```

Comment: thanks you very much.But how to get the particullar value.for example, i want to get Two value here...

Comment: You would use `intMap["Two"]` like a normal array accessor. You will be given an object of type `int` due to the strong-typing, whereas with the Hashtable you would only be given an `object`.

Comment: you can get a value in this way : intvalue=hashTable["Two"]

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) data structure, using `string` for the key type and whatever you data's type is for the value type (possibly `object` if multiple types of data items).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dictionary in c# see examples at http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-keys

Answer (score 1):

Saravanan

Java Map equals C# Dictionary (more or less)... and you'll want the generics version, of course.

This (at a quick glance) looks like a decent example. http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-lookup

Also you might want to take a geezer at: http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html ... I've found it to be extremely helpful with getting up-to-speed in C#.

Cheers. Keith.